# How to access an element of an xml which ends with specific characters using perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

my xml file has nodes as follows, However the name of second child node is not always the same. But it always ends with the same extension, in this case text. How can I access those nodes. Please help. I have used XML::LibXML in perl.

```
<Root>
            <ele1>"text"</ele1>
            <name attr="xxxxx">
              <value>10</value>
              <xxtext>90</xxtext>
            </name>
            <name attr="yyyy">
              <value>30</value>
              <yytext>100</yytext>
            </name>
</Root>
```

The code:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location=>$xml);
foreach my $sec ($parser->findnodes('/Root/name)) {
    my $value=$sec->findnodes('./value'); print $value,"\n";
    my $ias=$sec->findnodes('./*text');                        -------------? This is where I am facing problem.
    }
```

It works to find the tag value but I couldn't access the elements with tags ending with ias in this case. I was wondering if there is a way to access these type of tags. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using an XML parser? Or any other Perl code? You should show us earlier attempts.

Comment: Okay, I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Also, never say "its not working", say *how* it is not working. Otherwise people have to guess. I am guessing right now that it prints nothing, for example. Do you get other data from the file?

Comment: Give me a min, I cannot share the xml But I will try to depict what I did.
Now I have updated, hope this helps to solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: When I fix the errors in your XML, I still get an error from findnodes: `XPath error : Invalid expression
element/*text`

Comment: I get the same error, I don't know how to access that node, because it has different name everytime. But the last characters are same. What can I use instead of star, I have no idea.

Comment: The documentation is not particularly helpful. https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath#findnodes($path,-[$context])

Comment: Is the position of the target element among its siblings guaranteed? Then you may use the xpath expression `./*[last()]`.

Comment: That worked. Yes the position is guaranteed. Thanks for the idea so much :)

Comment: @TLP thanks for the guiding throughout those tips were helpful too.

Comment: Re "*with tags ending with ias*", huh? There are no  elements with a name ending with `ias` in the XML you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the position of the target element among its siblings is known, you can address it through xpath functions `last()`or `position()`:

```
my $ias=$sec->findnodes('./*[last()]');
```

or

```
my $ias=$sec->findnodes('./*[position() = 2]');
```

**Alternative**

You may also address (parts of) the element name of the target nodes which is provided through the `name()` function:

```
my $ias=$sec->findnodes('*[ends-with(name(), "text")]');
```

However, the `ends-with()` function requires XPath 2 support.

**Note**

There are various sites to test XPath expressions, eg. [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html). Substitute  `//name` for `.` in the XPath expressions from your code when trying.